# Find indexes of element in list that satisfies a condition in R

Tags: r

I have a list (I named it `lst`) with 150 elements, some of which contain `1`:

```
list(integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), 
    integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), 
    integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), 
    integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), 
    integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), 
    integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), 
    integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), 
    integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), 
    integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), 
    integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), 
    integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), 
    integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), 
    integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), 
    integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), 
    integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), 
    integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), 
    integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), 
    integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), 
    integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), 
    integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), 
    integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), 
    integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), 
    integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), 
    integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), 
    integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), 
    integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), 
    integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), 
    integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)
```

How do I extract out the **indexes**  of those elements that contain `1`. The result would be `139 140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150`.

I've tried:

`unlist(lapply(lst, function(x) if (x == 1) x))`

Comment: Try `Filter(length, your_list)` for getting **ALL** elements that are not `integer(0)`

Comment: Is this a list with Elements of length one? If so, why not convert it to a vector before trying to operate on it?

Comment: @Julian_Hn If I try `as.vector(unlist(lst))` it just strips away the `integer(0)` elements,  so not good

Comment: How about `which(your_list == 1)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Will do, @Ronak. logical operators (i.e., `==`) search in the first "level" of a list, and `which` returns the positions that are `TRUE`:

```
your_list == 1
  [1]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
 [27]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
 [53]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
 [79]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[105]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[131]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE

which(your_list == 1)
 [1] 139 140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150
```

Answer (score 0):

The tricky part is because of `integer(0)` elements. We can use `all.equal`

```
which(sapply(lst, all.equal, 1) == TRUE)
#[1] 139 140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `setequal`.  Should also work when the lengths of vector is greater than 1 for each `list` element

```
which(sapply(lst, setequal, 1))
#[1] 139 140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150
```

Or with `map` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
which(map_lgl(lst, setequal, 1))
#[1] 139 140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150
```

---

Or another option is `lengths`

```
which(lengths(lst) == 1)
```